# The error is shown till the screen is bring tapped

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

No such method error arises until the screen is tapped and works fine after. 
The widget used is Flutter Tinder card and data is being read from firebase database.!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8IVh.jpg)[]

Comment: where is your error?

Comment: where is your code? You need to check data first if you use future/stream builder.